# How to inflate a ListView upon clicking a Button

Tags: java, android, listview, android-inflate

Whenever a button is clicked, I want all the listview items to inflate just like a menuInflater inflates menu items. Upon clicking an item in the inflated listview, I want the button's color to change.

The problem here is that the listview is dynamic, its contents depend on user input and I can't seem to find a way to inflate a dynamic listview.

Comment: post your java code

Comment: I would but for what reason? I'm not even close to the desired result.